# Use table as constant values in VBA with listobjects

Tags: vba, excel

Following from a previous question, I have code which updates specific cells within a dynamic table based upon the contents of header row and first column.  The constant values are fixed values in the code but I now need to be able to reference this to a mapping table to that multiple cells can be updated in one go.

The existing code and an example of the table I need to work with are below.

```
sub ChangeTable()

Dim wsMapping As Worksheet
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim hdrCount As Long

Const ACCT_NO = "ABCD1234"
Const HEADING = "Analysis/*"
Const NEW_VAL = "80321"


Set wsData = Worksheets("Test Sheet")
Set wsMapping = Worksheets("Mapping")


Set tbl = wsData.ListObjects("Data")
hdrCount = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Columns.Count

For x = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
    With tbl.ListRows(x)
        If .Range(1, 1).Value2 = ACCT_NO Then
            For i = 2 To hdrCount
                If (tbl.HeaderRowRange(i).Value2 Like HEADING) Then
                    If (Not IsEmpty(.Range(1, i).Value)) Then
                    .Range(1, i).Value = NEW_VAL
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

On a separate sheet in Excel, there will be a table with a column for the account number and the new value.  There could be up to 10 different account numbers to change and this may be variable each time the file is produced, so the code needs to be able to deal with a variable number of constants each time it is used.

```
ABCD1234    80310
ABCD1235    80311
ABCD1236    80312
ABCD1237    80313
ABCD1238    80314
ABCD1239    80315
ABCD1240    80316
```

I think I would need to define the table range and say something like:

If not IsEmpty(Cells(x, 1)) Then (Const ACCT_NO = Cells(x, 1) AND Const NEW_VAL = Cells(x, 2))

and loop through each row in the table. Would this work?

Comment: You beat me to it Scott, I was just tidying up the table as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you can't change the value stored in a constant (they are, by definition, constant, i.e. unchanging) it sounds like you are on the right track.

Declare your current constants as normal string variables (e.g. `Dim ACCT_NO As String`) and then you can use `If not IsEmpty(Cells(x, 1)) Then ACCT_NO = Cells(x, 1): NEW_VAL = Cells(x, 2)` in a loop.

Probably your code will end up looking like this:

```
Sub ChangeTable()

    Dim wsMapping As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim x As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rowAcctNo As Long
    Dim lastrowAcctNo As Long
    Dim wsAcctNo As Worksheet
    Dim hdrCount As Long

    Dim ACCT_NO As String
    CONST HEADING = "Analysis/*"
    Dim NEW_VAL As String

    Set wsData = Worksheets("Test Sheet")
    Set wsMapping = Worksheets("Mapping")
    Set wsAcctNo = Worksheets("AcctNos") 'or whatever the sheet is called
    'Determine how many account number rows to process
    With wsAcctNo
        lastrowAcctNo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set tbl = wsData.ListObjects("Data")
    hdrCount = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Columns.Count

    For rowAcctNo = 1 to lastRowAcctNo
        If Not IsEmpty(wsAcctNo.Cells(rowAcctNo, 1)) Then
            ACCT_NO = wsAcctNo.Cells(rowAcctNo, 1).Value
            NEW_VAL = wsAcctNo.Cells(rowAcctNo, 2).Value
            For x = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
                With tbl.ListRows(x)
                    If .Range(1, 1).Value2 = ACCT_NO Then
                        For i = 2 To hdrCount
                            If (tbl.HeaderRowRange(i).Value2 Like HEADING) Then
                                If (Not IsEmpty(.Range(1, i).Value)) Then
                                    .Range(1, i).Value = NEW_VAL
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```